# How do I convert from utc to another timezone using moment?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

How do I convert from utc timestamp for example 1641148200000 to another timezone for ex. America/New_York?

I tried `moment(1641148200000).tz('America/New_York').format()` and I get the error that undefined.

How can I fix this?

Note that 1641148200000 is in UTC timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You need moment-timezone (with data) to use .tz function

```js
var m = moment(1641148200000).tz('America/New_York').format();
console.log(m);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.34/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```